# Postfix - copy email sent to a user@example.com address to another local address

Tags: postfix

I want to save the email that are going to a list of our customers to a archive email box. So if one of the employees is sending an email to user@example.com from employee@company.com, I want that email to go (as BCC) to archive@company.com. At the moment we are using Thunderbird configured with BCC, but for some reason, some of the employees are deleting that line... I need something idiot proof. Is this possible using postfix? Can you give me a hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [recipient_bcc_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps).